# Linux terminal pauses all text output every time I highlight something or click on the terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

How do I disable this from happening?

I'll run a build or install script and expect it to continue but I have a sort of nervous habit of clicking around a lot and highlighting things.

This stops my scripts from continuing to display output text and I have to hit enter to resume the script output, but sometimes I don't know if it's even stopped, because there's no indication that the text output has been paused.

How do I stop this behavior? I just want the terminal to ignore me doing stuff while a script is running.

Comment: is it a terminal in a linux OS or is it a WSL terminal on windows?

Comment: @ManishDash It's a WSL terminal on windows, but I've noticed the problem occurs on my raspbian build at work, too, so I didn't specify that.

Answer (score 0):

The script should continue to run if you minimize the terminal window (not close).

Then you should be able to click around as you wish because it will be elsewhere.

That method works here for me.

You really do not want to be typing in the terminal window itself. You can open a second terminal if you need a second terminal window.

You can easily switch between terminal windows to check the script.

So very easy overall with how terminal works.

**Follow up note:** Second terminal also works in WSL.  So anywhere you have a Linux terminal, you can open two and doodle in the second one.

Comment: Actually, I meant that the script will run, but the text output will stop. So sometimes I'll sit there waiting for 5 minutes for a build to finish and not realize it finished 4.5 minutes ago because the console output stopped when I clicked the terminal. It's a nervous habit, so I can try to click off of it, but chances are I will continue doing it so I just want to know if there's a way I can disable the "pause output text" behavior when I click around.